# Parametrization of surface for Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Compute $\oint_L \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{L}$ where $A=(yz+2z,xy-x+z,xy+5y)$ and $L$ is the line of intersection between the cylinder $x^2+z^2=4$ and the plane $x+y=2$. It is oriented such that the tangential vector at $(2,0,0)$ is $(0,0,1)$

**Attempted solution**

The rotation of the vector field is found to be $(x+4,2,y-1-z)$. A parametrization for the surface $S$ with $L$ as its boundary is given by $$\mathbf{r}(x,z)=\begin{cases} x=x \\ y=2-x \\z=z \end{cases}$$ for points $x,z$ such that $x^2+z^2 \leq 4$. This gives the normal vector $\hat{n} = \dfrac{\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial x} \times \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial z}}{|\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial x} \times \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial z}|} = (-1,-1,0)/\sqrt{2}\: $. Using Stokes' theorem we obtain $$\oint_L \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{L} = \iint_S \nabla \times \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \iint_S (x+4,2,y-1-z)\cdot (-1,-1,0)\: dS= \\= \iint_S-x-6 \: dS$$

Here I don't see how to continue. How can I determine $dS$ and the limits?

Comment: $x=x, y = 2-x, z = z$ parametrizes your surface in terms of $x$ and $z$. $dS = (-1,-1,0)\ dx\ dz.$  Now use your equations for the cylinder to find limits for $x,$ and $z,  \int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} -x-6\ dx\ dz$  Or, convert to cylindrical.  $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^2 -\cos\theta-6\ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: Should be "$-r\cos\theta$" in the last expression above.  Sorry, to late to edit comments.

Comment: @DougM Ah I thought that first integral would be too nasty. Should be $dz \: dx$ though, no?

Comment: With the limits as they are there, yes, $\ dz\ dx$ However, since the region is symmetric about $x=z$ a snap to flip the order of integration, if you like.   The integration is actually pretty simple first-year calculus stuff once you get started.  It is 6 times the area if the cross section of the cylinder.